# (Discord.py) Problem with slash commands (app_commands)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having trouble with making slash commands. So, I'm learning how to create app commands in discord.py, but my bot doesn't respond to the commands. By the way, i didn't get any error messages.

**Cog**

```
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext.commands import Context
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ping.py is ready!")


    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        yo = round(self.bot.latency * 1000)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Pong! :ping_pong:", color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.add_field(name="Latency:", value=f"{yo}ms")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    @app_commands.command(name="hi", description="Say hi!")
    async def hi(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, word:str):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hi {word}!")

    @app_commands.command(name="num", description="Random numbers")
    async def num(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, *, first: int, second: int) -> None:
        szam = random.randint(first, second)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Random number", color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.add_field(name=f"{context.author}'s number is:{szam}", value=f"Lowest:{first} | Highest:{second}",
                        inline=False)
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    @app_commands.command(name="test", description="test")
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, szam:str):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Szám:{szam}")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

**Main.py**

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import requests
import json
from discord.utils import get
from discord.utils import find
import datetime
import random
from discord import app_commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Successfully connected to the server!")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(bot.guilds)} server | !help"))


async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load()
        await bot.start("")


asyncio.run(main())
```

**P.S: The "hi" command works fine, but there others are not working.**

I checked the bot's intents, and the bot's permissions, but everything is fine and the commands still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In discord.py 2, you have to sync the commands (in order for them to show up) yourself using [app_commands.CommandTree.sync](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync). Modified [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L22-L28) from discord.py GitHub.

```py
MY_GUILD = discord.Object(id=0)  # replace with your guild id

# In this basic example, we just synchronize the app commands to one guild.
# Instead of specifying a guild to every command, we copy over our global commands instead.
# By doing so, we don't have to wait up to an hour until they are shown to the end-user.
async def setup_hook():
    # This copies the global commands over to your guild.
    bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=MY_GUILD)
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=MY_GUILD)

bot.setup_hook = setup_hook
```

You can look at this [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-bot-s-commands-are-not-showing-up) for more information.